# Flutter path_provider package error with Hive Database and null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, nullable

I have this error in my Flutter Project when I try to use Hive with path_provider. Is there any way to resolve this because i tried switching between beta and master channel and also setting flutter sdk min to 2.11.

This error is displayed when I call `path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`

```
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:121:86)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:146:36)
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
#3      MethodChannelPathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsPath (package:path_provider_platform_interface/src/method_channel_path_provider.dart:50:10)
#4      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:138:40)
#5      initDatabase (package:translator/main.dart:16:9)
#6      main (package:translator/main.dart:11:9)
#7      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25)
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
#9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
#11     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.d<…>
```

Here is my setup:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

...
dependencies
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
```

Comment: whats in here platform_channel.dart:121:86?

Answer (score 2):

After searching, I found this will fix the issue:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized; <--- problem here, missing()


WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
Directory document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```